# calling of one taxonomy from another taxonomy, so both of them have used in the same content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

**Can** we call one taxonomy term from another as a parent and child relation for example I need to click on product category and that show me product series page and when I click on product each series that will lead me to actual product detail means node, so I have two taxonomies category and series I am about to click on category to carry me to series page and then to click on series page to carry me to product detail page on the concern series”

no codebase problem

i am expecting that these two taxonomies may be used as i have mentioned in the question summary but, i can't do it so i hope some help in resolving this issue

Comment: Kindly upload screenshot

Comment: kindly have a look at https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/taxonomy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at this answer, I hope it will help you.
**Taxonomy terms from the same vocabulary filtered and referenced on multiple content types**

To do this you’ll need to have the Entity Reference module installed. So get that out of the way quickly with `drush dl entity reference -y` and `drush en entityreference -y` if you haven't already.

First up, we need the taxonomy set up.
Let's demonstrate with the help of an image.

[image]

You’ll notice that these terms could be more or less grouped into two categories: `Transport` and `Sleeping`. One term `(couchette)` kinda fits both criteria and is there to exemplify the reason for not using 2 different vocabularies to handle the issue. Now we need to technically make the distinction between these terms as well and since they are entities, we can use a field for that.

So we can now go ahead and add a new field to this vocabulary of the type List (text) with whatever widget you’d like (and let’s call the field Type). You should make the allowed number of values unlimited and put the following in the allowed values list:

Edit each term and select the appropriate type. As expected, for the term couchette, you should select both options.

Now that we have our taxonomy squared away, it’s time to create a View that will handle the filtering of these terms. Because if we now add the Tags taxonomy term reference field to our content types in the normal fashion (as it is already present in the Article content type) we’ll be able to select all the terms in the vocabulary for all the content types. And that's not what we want now.

So create a drupal 7/8 View that shows taxonomy terms of the Tags vocabulary - let’s call it Tags Filter. Add 2 displays of the type Entity Reference and a filter of the field we added to our terms earlier. So for instance the first display can show the terms which have Sleeping selected and the other one can show terms which have Transport. Save the View and you can close it.

Now finally we can edit our content types and add to each a new field of the type Entity Reference with a select list widget. For the target type select Taxonomy term and under Entity Selection choose the following: for Mode, go with Views: filter by entity reference view and then select the View in question - one of the two displays which we created earlier. In the picture below, I named one of the displays

[image]